# Replacing fragment on the fly

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
Android Studio 0.5.8
```

Hello,

I have one activity (`MainActivity`) that will host 2 fragments (`ListAddressBookFragment`, `AddAddressBookFragment`) (only one at a time). The initial fragment will be the `ListAddressBookFragment` and will be inflated when `MainActivity` onCreate gets called.

```
/* MainActivity.java */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* Add and display fragment */
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.flFragmentContainer);

    /* Create new fragment if this hasn't already been done */
    if(fragment == null) {
        fragment = new ListAddressBookFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.flFragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

In the `ListAddressBookFragment` I have a option menu to add a new addressbook item. So this will call call MainActivity. So I want to replace `ListAddressBookFragment` with `AddAddressBookFragment`. However, because the code above is hardcoded I am wondering is there anyway to do this on the fly?

```
/* ListAddressBookFragment.java */
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.new_addressbook) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to read this article, [Communicating with fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html.)

Basically, you need to call

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
```

Also, consider using interface within fragment that activity implements.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass data to the MainActivity to indicate the mode you want the activity to be in?

```
intent.putExtra("mode", "addressbook");
```

In the MainActivity, you do the below.

```
    String mode = (String)getIntent().getStringExtra("mode");
    if ("addressbook".equals(mode)) {
    // Address book fragment
    } else {
    // ListAddressBookFragment
    }
```

Good Luck

Comment: You can also add/delete/hide fragments. Check this article which has an example. http://www.intertech.com/Blog/programmatically-working-with-android-fragments/

Comment: I did think about that. I was just wondering if there was anything else better. Thanks

Comment: Another option is to create both the fragments in onCreate but leave one as hidden (start with addressbook as hidden). When address book menu is selected, make it visible and hide the list. You don't even need to start the MainActivity again. All you need to do is control the visibility. I think this is more efficient.